# How can I check if a string contains only English characters, exclamation marks at the end?

Tags: python, string

For example, "hello!!" should return true, whereas "45!!","!!ok" should return false. The only case where it should return true is when the string has English characters (a-z) with 0 or more exclamation marks in the end.

The following is my solution using an iterative method. However, I want to know some clean method having fewer lines of code (maybe by using some Python library).

```
def fun(str):
    i=-1
    for i in range(0,len(str)):
        if str[i]=='!':
            break
        elif (str[i]>='a' and str[i]<='z'):
            continue
        else:
            return 0

    while i<len(str):
        if(str[i]!='!'):
            return 0
        i+=1

    return 1

print(fun("hello!!"))
```

Comment: Your last sentence pretty much describes what regular expression to use. Have you looked at the `re` module?

Comment: By "English characters" you seem to mean only _letters_, right? What about upper case? Hyphens? spaces?

Comment: By “English” do you mean ASCII characters?  (Many languages use the same characters as the English language.)

Comment: @rickdenhaan Thanks. I will read about re module and regular expression.

Comment: @alexis I have mentioned in my question "characters (a-z) with 0 or more exclamation marks in the end". Thus only small case letters from 'a' to 'z'. No hypens or spaces.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412717).

Comment: @azro As cigien has mentioned, this question is being discussed on meta. I will be thankful for your thoughts there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex can help you out here.
The regular expression you're looking for here is:

```
^[a-z]+!*$
```

This will allow one or more English letters (lowered case, you can add upper case as well if you'll go with `^[a-zA-Z]+!*$`, or any other letters you'd like to add inside the square brackets)
and zero or more exclamation marks at the end of the word.

Wrapping it up with python code:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'^[a-z ]+!*$')
word = pattern.search("hello!!")
print(f"Found word: {word.group()}")
```